# Running mount -a generates this error

Tags: mount

This is my fstab

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Mon Dec 29 13:09:14 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=13141ff0-6270-40f8-87eb-3b10a3f004af   /   ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0    1   1
UUID=d0e3bc2c-64f8-4dfe-b8eb-dceedf53f458 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=613ac2aa-4bb3-4020-a535-d00e3ab007e4 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0

/dev/sdf1               /home1                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 0
```

if I type

I got:

```
root@host [/home1]# mount -a
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

What should I do?

I just replace this line

```
/dev/sdf1               /home1                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 0
```

from

```
/dev/sdb1               /home1                  auto    auto,noatime,defaults        0 0
```

Comment: Post the output of command `mount /dev/sdf1`

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sdf1 is either not formatted or is formatted with a filesystem that your installation doesn't know about. Run parted /dev/sdf and then type print, should give you FS info. There are other ways too but I can't remember offhand lol